# Getting an error when deploying to heroku "faliled to load resource 404 " bundle.js

Tags: node.js, postgresql, heroku, webpack

I am trying to deploy my app to heroku but it's throwing this error that I listed in the title. I'm using webpack to bundle the files into the file **bundle.js** I'm just not sure how to deploy this to heroku so that bundle.js will be available. How do you reconcile webpack with heroku? I am going to attach my db.js file and package.json file.

**db.js**

```
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');
var env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
var sequelize;

if (env === 'production') {
    sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env.DATABASE_URL, {
        dialect: 'postgres'
    }); // This if statement should execute if the app is run on Heroku
} else {
    sequelize = new Sequelize(undefined, undefined, undefined, {
        'dialect': 'sqlite',
        'storage': __dirname + '/data/practice-todo-api.sqlite'
    });
}



var db = {};

db.todo = sequelize.import(__dirname + '/models/todo.js');
db.user = sequelize.import(__dirname + '/models/user.js');
db.token = sequelize.import(__dirname + '/models/token.js');
db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

db.todo.belongsTo(db.user);
db.user.hasMany(db.todo);

module.exports = db;
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "practice-todo-api",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.9.1",
    "bcrypt": "^0.8.5",
    "body-parser": "^1.13.3",
    "crypto-js": "^3.1.5",
    "express": "^4.13.3",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^5.0.5",
    "lodash": "^3.10.1",
    "moment": "^2.11.2",
    "pg": "^4.4.1",
    "pg-hstore": "^2.3.2",
    "react": "^0.14.7",
    "react-dom": "^0.14.7",
    "react-redux": "^4.0.0",
    "react-router": "^2.0.0-rc5",
    "redux": "^3.0.4",
    "redux-form": "^4.1.3",
    "redux-promise": "^0.5.1",
    "request": "^2.60.0",
    "sequelize": "^3.17.1",
    "sqlite3": "^3.1.1",
    "underscore": "^1.8.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.5.1",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.2",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.5.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.5.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.5.0",
    "file-loader": "^0.8.5",
    "webpack": "^1.12.13"
  }
}
```

Comment: is your app working in development on localhost?

Answer (score 4):

Heroku recognizes a script called `postinstall` as part of the deployment lifecycle, which it executes after running `npm install`. In the `postinstall` script, specify the command you use to transpile your `bundle.js` file.

For example:

```
...
"scripts": {
  "build": "webpack --config ./config/webpack.config.js --progress --colors",
  "start": "node server.js",
  "postinstall": "npm run build" // referencing the "build" script above
},
...
```

Some helpful resources:

- http://ditrospecta.com/javascript/react/es6/webpack/heroku/2015/08/08/deploying-react-webpack-heroku.html
- https://github.com/alanbsmith/react-node-example/
- https://github.com/data-creative/express-on-rails-starter-app/tree/mongo-deploy-react

Comment: That was very helpful, I struggled much with this... The problem was the lack of the "postinstall" script that transpiles the js :D
my scripts:
    "prepublish": "npm i",
    "start": "node index.js",
    "postinstall": "./node_modules/.bin/webpack"